# ERROR: list does not name a type (C++). I don't think so?

Tags: c++, list, types

So I have been building on a small example of classes I found floating around to better prepare me for some C++ coding assignments in the future.  Trying to compile this code gives me an error: "classExample.cpp:12:2: error: 'list' does not name a type".

The only problem is, I most definitely assigned it's type to be of Rectangle* as you can see in the code below.  What am I doing wrong?

```
// classes example
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class setOfRectangles {
    list<Rectangle*> rectangles;
};

class Rectangle {
    int width, height; //class variables

  public:   //method constructors
    Rectangle(){width = 0;  //constructor for rectangle
        height = 0;}
    Rectangle(int i, int j){width = i; height=j;}
    void set_values (int,int);
    string toString();
    int area() {return width*height;}
    int perimeter(){return (2*width)+(2*height);}
};

void Rectangle::set_values (int x, int y) { //fleshing out class method
  width = x;
  height = y;
}

string Rectangle::toString()
{
    /*
        Prints information of Rectangle
        Demonstrates int to string conversion (it's a bitch)
    */

    std::stringstream sstm; //declare a new string stream

    sstm << "Width = ";
    sstm << width;

    sstm << "\n";

    sstm << "Height = ";
    sstm << height;

        sstm << "\n";

    sstm << "Perimeter = ";
    sstm << perimeter();

    sstm << "\n";

    return sstm.str(); //return the stream's string instance
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if(argc != 3)
    {
        cout << "Program usage: rectangle <width> <height> \n";
        return 1;
    }   
    else
    {
        Rectangle rect = Rectangle(2,3); //new instance, rectangle is 0x0
        cout << "area: " << rect.area() << "\n";
        cout << rect.toString() << endl;

        //call this method
        rect.set_values (atoi(argv[1]),atoi(argv[2]));

        cout << "area: " << rect.area() << "\n";
        cout << rect.toString() << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Class `setOfRectangles` has a member of type `list`, but no declaration has been provided for it. Do `#include <list>`.

Comment: I included the list header like you suggested, only now my error is: "12:17: template argument 1 is invalid."

Comment: You need also to declare type `Rectangle`. A C++ compiler needs to "know" what an identifier refers to before doing something with it.

Comment: I don't understand.  I'm used to the Java way of initializing lists as in "List<typeOfObject> nameOfList;"  What do I need to add to the class?

Comment: @user3448085 You just have to declare the Rectangle class before the setOfRectangles class.

Comment: `list<Rectangle>` is more natural than `list<Rectangle *>`.  Unless you actually require the extra level of indirection I'd recommend doing the former. Then you don't have to worry about memory management.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the proper header for `list`: `#include <list>`

Also, why are you including the C header `<stdlib.h>` in a C++ application? Is it for `atoi`? If so, you should look into how to do casts in C++ in the proper way. Or include `<cstdlib>` instead (which is the C++ version of the same header).

Also, you need to move this:

```
class setOfRectangles {
    list<Rectangle*> rectangles;
};
```

to after the declaration of `class Rectangle`, or the compiler won't know what a Rectangle is.